# CSS "d" path - attribute doesn't work in Safari, FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, safari

I want use CSS animation for attribute "d" to SVG path.
This example working in Google chrome:

```css
body {
  background-color: #022040;
}

#path {
  d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L675,275 L775,175 L875,275 L925,225'); 
  stroke: #1EFE64;
  fill: none;
  animation-name: path;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes path {

  0% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275');
  }

  25% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L575,175 L575,175 L575,175 L575,175');
  }
  
  50% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L675,275 L675,275 L675,275 L675,275'); 
  }
  
  75% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L675,275 L775,175 L775,175 L775,175'); 
  }
  
  90% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L675,275 L775,175 L875,275 L875,275'); 
  }
  
  100% {
     d: path('M425,225 L475,275 L575,175 L675,275 L775,175 L875,275 L925,225'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="400">
<path id="path" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
```

But doesn't work in Safari Pc/Mobile and FireFox.

How to fix the bug?
Or should I use the tag "animate" in svg?

Help me please)
Thank you!

Comment: These browsers only support d as an attribute, not as CSS. You can redo the animation in SMIL if you want to support them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`d` is an SVG “Geometry Property” defined in the SVG 2 specification at https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/paths.html#TheDProperty. Google Chrome’s Blink layout engine is the only layout engine to support this property and its implementation doesn’t match the current specification definition.

Relevant Issue Tracker Pages:

- [Bugzilla@Mozilla Bug 1383650](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1383650)
- [Microsoft Edge Development Issue 11543103](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11543103/)
- [Monorail Issue 652822](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652822)

And, yes, you can achieve the same effect using the SVG `animate` element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <title>Path Animation</title>
    <path fill="none" stroke="hsl(139, 99%, 56%)" stroke-width="20">
        <animate attributeName="d" values="
            M 425 225 L 475 275;
            M 425 225 L 475 275 L 575 175 L 575 175 L 575 175 L 575 175 L 575 175;
            M 425 225 L 475 275 L 575 175 L 675 275 L 675 275 L 675 275 L 675 275;
            M 425 225 L 475 275 L 575 175 L 675 275 L 775 175 L 775 175 L 775 175;
            M 425 225 L 475 275 L 575 175 L 675 275 L 775 175 L 875 275 L 875 275;
            M 425 225 L 475 275 L 575 175 L 675 275 L 775 175 L 875 275 L 925 225
        " keyTimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 0.9; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.42 0 1 1; 0.42 0 1 1; 0.42 0 1 1; 0.42 0 1 1; 0.42 0 1 1" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
</svg>
```

`0.42 0 1 1` is the set of cubic Bézier values for the `ease-in` `animation-timing-function` property keyword as defined in the CSS Timing Functions, Level 1 specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-timing-1/#valdef-cubic-bezier-timing-function-ease-in.

Comment: UPDATE for 2022: you can now use d as a CSS property in Firefox and Microsoft Edge. Safari still not supported