# svg path transition in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate a changing d path in the svg file format. It works fine in Google Chrome and IE, but in Safari it doesn't show an animation

```css
 -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
```

and

```css
-webkit-transition-property: 0.9s;
```

don't work. How can I fix it?

```js
 function animationStart() {
     let element = document.getElementById('graph'); 
    element.setAttribute('d', 'M2,6 L5,3 L8,4 L11,4'); 
 }
```

```css
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  svg polyline,
  svg line,
  svg path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    transition: 0.9s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
    -webkit-transition-property: 0.9s;
  }

  .container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" class="svg-1">
   <path stroke-width="0.1" d="M1,1 L3,3 L4,1 L5,2" id="graph"/>
 </svg>

 <button onclick="animationStart()">Click to draw</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Safari doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467444

Comment: Your code doesn't work in *Firefox* either.